# Python Code to Convert Email Originated Image Files into PDF

Tags: python, automation, invoice

trying to solve a business problem I'm having.

I need to be able to direct invoices received via email to a program that can only read files in PDF format. These invoices are images usually in PNG or JPEG formats.

I'd like to figure out a Python code that allows me to send these non-PDF forms, like PNG/JPEG, to a specific address either online or locally that can automatically convert these files into PDF so I can send them to the program. The program only accepts email uploads with PDF attachments. I have many invoices coming through so I need something that can handle multiple files being converted.

I don't know where to start so any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks

Comment: First, check if the program supports non-searchable PDFs which is what you'll get when you convert an image into PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access to received PNG/JPEG, it's possible to try [img2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) python package. You also can use it as a lib ([source](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/)):

```
import img2pdf    
# convert all files ending in .jpg inside a directory
    dirname = "/path/to/images"
    with open("name.pdf","wb") as f:
        imgs = []
        for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
            if not fname.endswith(".jpg"):
                continue
            path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                continue
            imgs.append(path)
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(imgs))
```

As soon as you convert images into PDF file, you can send to the processing server in a way you want (email, request, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I'm trying to run it but get an indentation error in the 3rd line. Any idea of why that might be?